# How to increase the chance that an old quote is selected

Tags: sql, h2

I have a database which contains quotes. I like to display random quotes. But with two conditions.

- Quotes that are displayed the last week should not be selected.
- How farther in the past a quote is displayed, the more chance it has to be to be selected.

The first is not so difficult. I can use the WHERE clause for this.

The second I do not know how to implement. Is there an easy way to do this, or need I to define a complex function for this?

One extension that could be nice also. Initially most quotes will not have been displayed. If it would be possible to give a quote that has not been displayed yet a much bigger chance to be displayed, then it would be quite nice.

Comment: Whcih DMBS are you using?

Comment: In this case H2 (http://www.h2database.com/), but I also use MySQL and SQLite for example. So I prefer a solution that is applicable in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible approach: order by the length of time in the past the quote was used, times a random number.  This has the effect of giving a greater weight to records further in the past.

Here is pseudo code:

```
select quote from quotes 
    where current date - display date > 1 week
    order by ((current date - display date - 1 week) * random number) desc
    fetch first row only
```

You will have to adapt it to your system's date/time functions, since these are highly variable.

You probably need to use an intermediate step to apply a random number to each row, because directly ordering by `rand()` doesn't work on many systems.

**Update:** Here is [a working MySQL example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f69af/13).

Comment: Looks quit interesting. I will delve into it.

Comment: That translate in H2 to: http://pastebin.com/7sjSCaFe  
    
The only strange thing is that 'Long, long ago' gets selected much more often as you should expect. In SQLFiddle and my H2 testing.  
  
For one reason or another linebreaks do not work in my comment. :-(